ERROR: Could not locate Python interpreter E:\pycharm\pyinterpreter\python.exe
My pip command doesn't work. A few months ago, I put down a pycharm and python on the U disk, and I also used the environment on the U disk, but recently the U disk was lost, and the computer can't use pip any instructions without adding the U disk, list and install can't work, the following is the cmd error message
Microsoft Windows
C:Users27669>where pipD:download\python_interpreter3.12.2\Scripts\pip.exeD:\python_3.10.9\Scripts\pip.exe
C:\Users\27669>pip listERROR: Could not locate Python interpreter E:\pycharm\pyinterpreter\python.exe
C:\Users\27669>where pythonD:\download\python_interpreter3.12.2\python.exeD:\python_3.10.9\python.exeC:\Users\27669\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps\python .exe
C:\Users\27669\Desktop\get-pip(1).pyC:\Users27669>D:\download\python_interpreter3.12.2\python.exeD: ldownload\python_interpreterl3.12.2\python.exe: can't open file 'c:llUsers![27669\11u202ac:\Usersl[27669\\Desktopllget-pip':[Errno 22]Invalid argument
C:\Users\27669>D:\download\python_interpreter\3.12.2\python.exe "c:\Users\27669\Desktop\get-pip (1).pyERROR: Could not locate Python interpreter E:\pycharm pyinterpreter \python.ex
C:\Users\27669>python print("hello world")python: can't open file 'c:\\Users\[27669\\print(hello world)': [Errno 2] No such file or directory
C:\Users\27669>pythonPython 3.12.2 (tags/v3.12.2:6abddd9,Feb 62024,21:26:36)[MSC v.1937 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32Type "help""credits"ulicense"for more information."copyright"Or>>> print("hello world")hello world

I tried removing all environment variables such as PATH that contains the E drive, installed the new python - 3.10.9 and used its pip directives, or ran the pip directives on pycharm, vscode terminals, but all the same error :ERROR: Could not locate Python interpreter E:pycharmpyinterpreter python.exe but python.exe works fine

it really bothered me a lot, i will be more than appreiciate it if you can help me  with it
